# Js child_process command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, exec, child-process

I have done the following two tests, to know the version of node I am using but I am getting the following errors.

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Test1:

```js
import { exec as cExec } from "child_process";
import { promisify } from "util";
const exec = promisify(cExec);

    const cmd = `node -v`;

    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(cmd);
    if (stderr) throw new Error(stderr);
    console.log(stdout);
```

Error1:

```
Error: Command failed: node -v
/bin/sh: node: command not found


/bin/sh: node: command not found
ChildProcess.exithandler:node:child_process:419:12
ChildProcess.emit:node:events:513:28
```

Test2:

```js
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');

    const ls = spawn('node', ['-v']);

    ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });
    
    ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });
    
    ls.on('close', (code) => {
      console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
```

Error2:

```
Error: spawn node ENOENT

ChildProcess._handle.onexit:child_process:283:19
onErrorNT:child_process:476:16
```

Comment: The `node` command is apparently not in your `PATH`. Try using the full path to `node`.

Comment: If I do it from the terminal it works.

Comment: You may have different `$PATH` setting.

Comment: What does `type node` show in the terminal?

Comment: node is /Users/nameUser/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node